# Issues programming ESP12F

Tags: pcb-design, esp8266

I used this wiring schematic for a couple of my ESP8266-12F projects for programming mode:

[image]

As I built enough confidence with the module, I decided to go ahead with a PCB design. When I try to upload a sketch, it wouldn't go into programming mode although I think my design is correct. I checked the connections between pads and headers and they all connected. Am I missing something here? Would you please check the connections and let me know of possible cause?

```
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM4'
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____...._____

esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0xE0)
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem recently. It was due to not enough capacitance on the power supply. Fatten up your gnd and vcc tracks and add a 22uF 25V ceramic capacitor close to the module pads. Note that it is not a good idea to run tracks under the antenna or even the pcb.

Answer (score 1):

Your top image shows TX to TX and RX to RX. Is that really correct or should it be TX to RX?

Comment: I used the upper wiring tens of times. However, I swapped TX & RX but got the same issue.

Comment: this answer should really be a comment

Comment: Your enable pin is pulled low on one and high on the other. 

And, are you enabling GPIO-0 to the proper high/low to enable programming of the ESP12F?